# adding formatted minutes in Scala

Tags: scala

How to add minutes in scala with the below format

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar

val cal = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
//val cal = Calendar.getInstance()


// create the date/time formatters
val dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd")
val monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM")
val yearFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy")
val hourFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH")
val minuteFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm")
val secondFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ss")

val year = yearFormat.format(cal);
val month = monthFormat.format(cal);
val day = dayFormat.format(cal);
val hour = hourFormat.format(cal);
val minute = minuteFormat.format(cal);
val second = secondFormat.format(cal);

val AxedaRecvdDt = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "T" + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + "Z"
```

Comment: First of all stop using old `Calendar` and start using `java.time` from Java 8. Then you only need one formatter (not six :/ ) for printing one String https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: What is your question? You are formatting minutes already (`minuteFormat`). By the way you do _not_ need a dozen formats, even with old-style Java calendar. You can use apostrophes `'foo'` to escape any arbitrary character sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Just do like below:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar

val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
//Why declare formats separately, format and concatenate when you can do just that in a single format
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30); // add mins here
val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
val AxedaRecvdDt = formatter.format(cal.getTime())
```

Comment: The above code is the sample and answer. Don't you see 'mm' in the above answer in the format?

Comment: yes i am seeing 'mm' .... i Wanna To add 30 minutes in current Time... not to  add simply minutes

Comment: if we use val cal = Calendar.getInstance().getTime() cal.add is not working (cannot resolve symbol)                                                                                                             if we use this  means val cal = Calendar.getInstance() will get error like "Cannot format given Object as a Date"

Comment: Thanks ... now i got it

Comment: i have  another query in scala                                                                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719333/using-ifelse-in-scala-for-multiple-function