# using ifelse in scala for multiple function

Tags: scala

I like to run the function inside the curly braces based on random number.but it is executing the last function only.
which one  have to be used it for gatling to execute multiple function like javascript

val scnPostAndGet = scenario("Post and get")
   .exec(Read_HDAS_Data, Hdas_location, Hdas_Token)
  .doIfOrElse(_ =>rnd<= 1)
   {abc;xyz;mainpower}

```
{lkg;skm;immidiate}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't understand your question, could you expand? E.g. a code example via http://scastie.org/ which doesn't do what you want.

Comment: if it match the condition it should executed all the funtions in if condition for me it is executing the last one..i need all the fucntion has to be executed for the above...which one i can use it to meet this criteria doIfOrElse  (Randnr >=1 && Randnr <= 2)
{

CreateException_Zone;
CreateException_Idling;
CreateException_IdlingSummary
}


{

CreateException_LowBattery;
CreateException_Stop

}

Comment: ifelse sounds like a match/case statement - try to rephrase your question with these.